# AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'schema'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This code doesn't work. I got it from [this webpage](http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial-0.1.html)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Dec 19 13:19:13 2015

@author: idf
"""

import sqlite3
import sqlalchemy
import sys

from sqlalchemy import *


print(sqlite3.version)
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
print(sqlalchemy.__version__)
print(sys.version) 

# This prints:
# 2.6.0
# 3.8.4.1
# 1.0.9
# 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01) 

#if I use this
# db = create_engine('sqlite:///joindemo.db')
# I get the error at end of post

db = create_engine('sqlite', opts={'filename': 'joindemo.db'})

db.echo = True

users = Table('users', db,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(40)),
    Column('age', Integer),
)
users.create()

emails = Table('emails', db,
    Column('email_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('address', String),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.user_id')),
)
emails.create()

i = users.insert()
i.execute(
    {'name': 'Mary', 'age': 30},
    {'name': 'John', 'age': 42},
    {'name': 'Susan', 'age': 57},
    {'name': 'Carl', 'age': 33}
)
i = emails.insert()
i.execute(
    # There's a better way to do this, but we haven't gotten there yet
    {'address': 'mary@example.com', 'user_id': 1},
    {'address': 'john@nowhere.net', 'user_id': 2},
    {'address': 'john@example.org', 'user_id': 2},
    {'address': 'carl@nospam.net', 'user_id': 4},
)

def run(stmt):
    rs = stmt.execute()
    for row in rs:
        print(row)

# This will return more results than you are probably expecting.
s = select([users, emails])
run(s)

# The reason is because you specified no WHERE clause, so a full join was
# performed, which returns every possible combination of records from
# tables A and B. With an appropriate WHERE clause, you'll get the
# restricted record set you really wanted.
#s = select([users, emails], emails.c.user_id == users.c.user_id)
#run(s)

# If you're interested in only a few columns, then specify them explicitly
#s = select([users.c.name, emails.c.address], 
#           emails.c.user_id == users.c.user_id)
#run(s)

# There are also "smart" join objects that can figure out the correct join
# conditions based on the tables' foreign keys
#s = join(users, emails).select()
#run(s)

# If you want all the users, whether or not they have an email address,
# then you want an "outer" join.
#s = outerjoin(users, emails).select()
#run(s)

# Order of outer joins is important! Default is a "left outer join", which
# means "all records from the left-hand table, plus their corresponding
# values from the right-hand table, if any". Notice how this time, Susan's
# name will *not* appear in the results.
#s = outerjoin(emails, users).select()
#run(s)
```

```
>>> runfile('/home/idf/Documents/Projects/python3/testsqlalchemy.py', wdir='/home/idf/Documents/Projects/python3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/home/idf/Documents/Projects/python3/testsqlalchemy.py", line 10, in <module>
    db = create_engine('sqlite', opts={'filename': 'joindemo.db'})
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 386, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 49, in create
    u = url.make_url(name_or_url)
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 186, in make_url
    return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 235, in _parse_rfc1738_args
    "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name)
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'sqlite'
>>>
```

This is the other error if I try `db = create_engine('sqlite:///joindemo.db')`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/home/idf/Documents/Projects/python3/testsqlalchemy.py", line 27, in <module>
    Column('age', Integer),
  File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 374, in __new__
    schema = metadata.schema
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'schema'
>>>
```

Comment: What sqlalchemy and sqlite versions are you using? Thanks.

Comment: Please, use the oficial tutorial for ORM: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial does not look up to date. The correct [engine creation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlite) should be:

```
db = create_engine('sqlite:///joindemo.db')
```

---

And you need to initialize [`MetaData` object now](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#module-sqlalchemy.schema):

```
metadata = MetaData(db)
```

and use it when you define your tables:

```
users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(40)),
    Column('age', Integer),
)
users.create()

emails = Table('emails', metadata,
    Column('email_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('address', String),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.user_id')),
)
emails.create()
```

---

As a side note, I would look for a different tutorial, this one does not really reflect what `SQLAlchemy` is today.

Comment: See the modified post where I say "#if I use this"

Comment: Thanks, that does appear to make the example work. Which example do you recommend?

Comment: @Ivan I cannot recommend any tutorial from the top of my head, but what I've been using is SO and SQLAlchemy docs - the docs are really-really good.

Comment: Ok will look around. BTW, if I uncomment the first commented out code to add a WHERE clause, it fails again. But, you got the original question working. Oops! It is because the db existed on disk already. Nevermind! The demo should delete the joindemo.db as the first thing it does so it doesn't confuse with errors.